# Pyspark: Window / Cumulative Sum with Condition

Tags: python, pyspark, window-functions, cumsum

Say I have data like so:

```
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3  | Col3                |
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| A    | 0.532 | 0.234 | 2020-01-01 05:00:00 |
| B    | 0.242 | 0.224 | 2020-01-01 06:00:00 |
| A    | 0.152 | 0.753 | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 |
| C    | 0.149 | 0.983 | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 |
| A    | 0.635 | 0.429 | 2020-01-01 09:00:00 |
| A    | 0.938 | 0.365 | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 |
| C    | 0.293 | 0.956 | 2020-01-02 05:00:00 |
| A    | 0.294 | 0.234 | 2020-01-02 06:00:00 |
| E    | 0.294 | 0.394 | 2020-01-02 07:00:00 |
| D    | 0.294 | 0.258 | 2020-01-02 08:00:00 |
| A    | 0.687 | 0.666 | 2020-01-03 05:00:00 |
| C    | 0.232 | 0.494 | 2020-01-03 06:00:00 |
| D    | 0.575 | 0.845 | 2020-01-03 07:00:00 |
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

I want to create another column that is:

- Sum of Col2
- Grouped by Col1
- Only for records outside of 2 hours prior to Col3

So, for this example, looking at A, and summing Col2

```
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3  | Col3                |
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| A    | 0.532 | 0.234 | 2020-01-01 05:00:00 | => Will be null, as it is the earliest
| A    | 0.152 | 0.753 | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 | => 0.532, as 05:00:00 is >= 2 hours prior
| A    | 0.635 | 0.429 | 2020-01-01 09:00:00 | => 0.532, as 08:00:00 is <2 hours, but 05:00:00 is >= 2 hours (08:00 is within 2 hours of 09:00)
| A    | 0.938 | 0.365 | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 | => 0.532 + 0.152, as 09:00:00 is < 2 hours, but 08:00:00 and 05:00:00 are >= 2 hours prior
| A    | 0.294 | 0.234 | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | => 0.532 + 0.152 + 0.635 + 0.938, as all of the ones on the same day are >= least 2 hours prior.
| A    | 0.687 | 0.666 | 2020-01-03 05:00:00 | => Will be null, as it is the earliest this day.
+------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

- I have thought about sorting them and doing a cumulative sum, but not sure how to exclude the ones inside of the 2-hour range.
- Have thought about grouping and summing with condition, but not totally sure how to execute that.
- Have also thought about emitting records to fill the gap such that they are all hours are filled in, and taking sum up until 2 prior. However, this would require me to transform the data as it is not inherently clean at the top of each hour; they are actual random timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **`Spark2.4+`** try this.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


w=Window().partitionBy("col1",F.to_date("col4", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).orderBy(F.unix_timestamp("col4"))\
           .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df\
  .withColumn("try", F.collect_list("col2").over(w))\
  .withColumn("try2", F.collect_list(F.unix_timestamp("col4")).over(w))\
  .withColumn("col5", F.arrays_zip("try","try2")).drop("try")\
  .withColumn("try3",F.element_at("try2", -1))\
  .withColumn("col5", F.when(F.size("try2")>1,F.expr("""aggregate(filter(col5, x-> x.try2 <= (try3-7200)),\
                                                     cast(0 as double), (acc,y)-> acc+y.try)""")).otherwise(None))\
  .drop("try3","try2").orderBy("col1","col4").show(truncate=False)

#+----+-----+-----+-------------------+------------------+
#|col1|col2 |col3 |col4               |col5              |
#+----+-----+-----+-------------------+------------------+
#|A   |0.532|0.234|2020-01-01 05:00:00|null              |
#|A   |0.152|0.753|2020-01-01 08:00:00|0.532             |
#|A   |0.635|0.429|2020-01-01 09:00:00|0.532             |
#|A   |0.938|0.365|2020-01-01 10:00:00|0.684             |
#|A   |0.294|0.234|2020-01-01 12:00:00|2.2569999999999997|
#|A   |0.687|0.666|2020-01-03 05:00:00|null              |
#|B   |0.242|0.224|2020-01-01 06:00:00|null              |
#|C   |0.149|0.983|2020-01-01 08:00:00|null              |
#|C   |0.293|0.956|2020-01-02 05:00:00|null              |
#|C   |0.232|0.494|2020-01-03 06:00:00|null              |
#|D   |0.294|0.258|2020-01-02 08:00:00|null              |
#|D   |0.575|0.845|2020-01-03 07:00:00|null              |
#|E   |0.294|0.394|2020-01-02 07:00:00|null              |
#+----+-----+-----+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I get an error in the -7200 section with timestamp subtracting an integer:


AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'subtracttimestamps(`try3`, 7200)' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires timestamp type, however, '7200' is of int type.

Comment: Never mind -- missed a unix timestamp conversion! It works!

How would you get a cumulative count in this same example (rather than a sum)?